# Using sub 1GHz 6LoWPAN, which development kits are available?

Tags: wireless, dev-kit

I need to create a network with 6LoWPAN, or maybe some others supporting IPv6, and are looking for development kits.

The ones I found are

- [Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc-6lowpan-dk-868) using Sensinode’s NanoStack
- [NIVIS](http://www.nivis.com/products/product.php?pID=17)

I would also like input on projects available that I can get some inspiration from. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Companies offer development kits that can help developers kick start a
>   6LoWPAN project or just investigate its capabilities. Sensinode
>   (www.sensinode.com) offers a K210 6LoWPAN Devkit and Atmel
>   (www.atmel.com) provides its 2.4 GHz Evaluation and Starter Kit
>   (ATAVRRZRAVEN) that runs a port of the Contiki 2.2.2 OS, which
>   contains the small uIPv6 stack and SICSlowpan 802.15.4-over-IPv6
>   compression (http://www.sics.se/contiki). Arch Rock (www.archrock.com)
>   has a PhyNet OEM Development Kit (IE version) that comes configured
>   with the PhyNet IE Engine that lets developers use direct C API calls
>   to the Arch Rock IP/6LoWPAN linkable kernel library to access
>   operating-system services and standard TCP/UDP/IP-based networks.
>   Jennic (www.jennic.com) also offers a 6LoWPAN Network Protocol stack
>   that operates with the company's JN5139 wireless microcontrollers and
>   modules.

You can check tutorials at

1. http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jwhui/6lowpan.html
2. http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC-6LoWPAN
3. [More About 6LoWPAN](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=robotics.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pister/290Q/Handouts/6LoWPAN-tutorial.pdf)

Comment: Sensinode is only available on TI's CCxxxx parts, so that I knew (as posted in question). Raven is only 2.4GHz, so is Jennic's and archrock's devices. While the tutorials are nice, I would like some more sub GHz solutions

Comment: CC-6LOWPAN-DK-868 Kit is 868/915 MHz development kit...I dont think you will get something at 1 GHz(until you plan to tweak it yourself).IEEE 802.15.4-conformant devices may use one of three possible frequency bands for operation.`(868.0-868.6 MHz,902-928 MHz,2400-2483.5 MHz)`

Comment: I said _SUB_ 1GHz, i.e 868/915 MHz for my part

Answer (score 1):

ZMDI's ZWIR4512. Stuff here: http://www.zmdi.com/products/rfid-wireless/zwir4512/

Comment: Please add some details here; when that link dies your answer becomes useless.